# PHP Escape Characters being pulled

Tags: php, encoding, escaping

I have a file that has a line of code like this:

```
$var = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"" . GLOBAL_PATH . "system/modules/" . $path . "/" . $css . "\" media=\"screen\">"
```

I'm opening it into a  then saving it back to the server. When I save back to the server using fwrite() and then reopen I get this:

```
$var = "<link rel="stylesheet" href="" . GLOBAL_PATH . "system/modules/" . $path . "/" . $css . "" media="screen">"
```

...where the slashes escaping the quotes are gone.

Comment: Can't you use single quotes for the string?

Comment: you need to escape the slashes if using fwrite, or maybe use single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not "gone", as they were technically not in the original string. Consider this:

```
$str = "\"";
echo strlen($str); // 1, not 2!
```

... as `$str` string stores only one symbol (a double quote mark), and backslash is used to prevent it from being misread as an ending of the string literal.

While PHP is able to magically restore 'lost' slashes (with `magic_quotes_runtime` directive), it's been deprecated in PHP 5.3 and *removed* in 5.4.

The alternative is using [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes) function when you *indeed* need them restored.

```
$str = "\"";
echo addslashes($str); // \"
```